# Pb with scrapy when CONCURRENT_REQUESTS > 1

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a newbie on python and thus on scrapy (tools to crawl website written in python...) too, hope someone can shed some lights on my way... I just wrote a spider consisting on 2 parsing fonctions:
  - the first parsing function to parse the start page I'm crawling & which contains chapters & sub-chapters with 7 levels, some of the chapters at various level pointing ( to articles or lists of articles
  - the second parsing function is there to parse the articles or list of articles and is invoked as the call back of scrapy.Request(...)
The objective of this spider is to create a sort of big DOM of the entire content with the chapters, sub-chapters, articles & their content.

I have a problem in the second function which seems to receive sometime responses that do not correspond the content located at the url used when invoking scrapy.Request. This problem disappeared when setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1. I initially thought that this was due to some multi-threading / non-re-entrant functions pb but found that I had no re-entrances issue and read afterwards that scrapy was actually not multi-threaded... so I cannot figure out where my pb comes from.

Here a snippet of my code

```
#---------------------------------------------
# Init part:
#---------------------------------------------
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

top = Element('top')
curChild = top

class mytest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lfb'

#
# This is what make my code working but I don't know why !!! 
# Ideally would like to benefit from the speed of having several concurrent
# requests when crawling & parsing 
#
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1',
    }

#
# This section is just here to be able to do something when the spider closes
# In this case I want to print the DOM I've created.
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(mytest, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print ("Spider closed - !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
#this is to print the DOM created at the end
        print tostring(top)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass


    def start_requests(self):
        level = 0
        print "Start parsing legifrance level set to %d" % level
# This is to print the DOM which is empty (or almost - just the top element in there)
        print tostring(top)
        yield scrapy.Request("<Home Page>", callback=self.parse)

#----------------------------------------------
# First parsing function - Parsing the Home page - this one works fine (I think)
#----------------------------------------------
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//span'):
            cl = sel.xpath("@class").extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
#
# Do some stuff here depending on the class (cl) of 'span' which corresponds 
# to either one of the # 7 levels of chapters & sub-chapters or to list of
# articles attached to a sub-chapters. To simplify I'm just putting here the 
# code corresponding to the handling of list of articles (cl == codeLienArt)
#           ...
#           ...
        if cl == [unicode('codeLienArt')]: 
            art_plink= sel.css('a::attr("href")').extract()
            artLink= "<Base URL>"+str(unicode(art_plink[0]))
#
# curChild points to the element in the DOM to which the list of articles
# should be attached. Pass it in the request meta, in order for the second
# parsing function to place the articles & their content at the right place
# in the DOM
#
            thisChild = curChild
#
# print for debug - thisChild.text contains the heading of the sub-chapter
# to which the list of articles that will be processed by parse1 should be
# attached.
#
            print "follow link cl:%s art:%s for %s" % (cl, sel.xpath('a/text()').extract(), thisChild.text )
#
# get the list of articles following artLink & pass the response to the second parsing function 
# (I know it's called parse1 :-)
#
            yield scrapy.Request(artLink, callback=self.parse1, meta={ 'element': thisChild })

#-------------------
# This is the second parsing function that parses list of Articles & their content
# format is basically one or several articles, each being presented(simplified) as
# < div class="Articles">
#   <div class="titreArt"> Title here</div>
#   <div class="corpsArt"> Sometime some text and often a list of paragraph    <p>sentences</p>" ></div>
#  </div>
#-------------------
    def parse1(self, resp):
    print "enter parse1"
    numberOfArticles= 0
    for selArt in resp.xpath('//div[@class="article"]'):
#
# This is where I see the problem when CONCURRENT_REQUESTS > 1, sometimes
# the response points to a page that is not the page that was requested in
# the previous parsing function...
#
        clArt = selArt.xpath('.//div[@class="titreArt"]/text()').extract()
        print clArt
        numberOfArticles += 1
        childArt = SubElement(resp.meta['element'], 'Article')
        childArt.text =str(unicode("%s" % clArt[0]))
        corpsArt = selArt.xpath('.//div[@class="corpsArt"]/text()').extract()
        print "corpsArt=%s" % corpsArt
        temp = ''
        for corpsItem in corpsArt:
            if corpsItem != '\n':
                temp += corpsItem

        if temp != '':
            childCorps =  SubElement(childArt, 'p')
            childCorps.text = temp
            print "corpsArt is not empty %s" % temp
        for paraArt in selArt.xpath('.//div[@class="corpsArt"]//p/text()').extract():
            childPara = SubElement(childArt, 'p')
            childPara.text = paraArt
            print "childPara.text=%s" % childPara.text

    print "link followed %s (%d)" % (resp.url,numberOfArticles)
    print "leave parse1"
    yield
```

Comment: What you are encountering here is called web sessions. Some websites store your whole session in a cookie so if two of your request chains share the same cookie you will encounter weird behaviour. Could you provide website link? The general solutions are either keep track of the cookies manually or preferrably if possible to disable them completely.

Comment: Home Page: https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072026&dateTexte=20170728.

Comment: Base url: https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/ and here is an exemple of a link to a list of article processed by parse1 https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=2CE73B0A4B1D110867205568C4A2C260.tpdila22v_1?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000020871602&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072026&dateTexte=20170728

Comment: So yes you're right there are sessions being managed here with jessionid but I'm not sure to understand why when there are more than one concurrent requests in // it explains why responses received by parse1 would not sometimes corespond to the requested url